# Service not running after app killed on Android 8 Oreo

Tags: android, service

i have a service for connecting my socket to server and i want restart this service when my app kill.

restarting service works fine on android 5 but not working on Oreo.

i tried so many ways to do this like : boardCastReceivers and changing manifest setting for service but not working

my codes:
in manifest

```java
       <service
            android:name="com.jeen.jeen.service.ChatService"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.jeen.jeen.service.ChatReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="RestartServiceWhenStopped"
            >
        </receiver>




in MainActivity:




@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        stopService(mServiceIntent);
        Log.i("MAINACT", "onDestroy!");
        super.onDestroy();

    }



    private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                Log.i ("isMyServiceRunning?", true+"");
                return true;
            }
        }
        Log.i ("isMyServiceRunning?", false+"");
        return false;
    }


    ChatService chatService;
    Intent mServiceIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        chatService = new ChatService(MainActivity.this);
        mServiceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, chatService.getClass());
        if (!isMyServiceRunning(chatService.getClass())) {
            startService(mServiceIntent);
        }



        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        }



receiver class: 


public class ChatReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(ChatReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), "Service fucked up");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, ChatService.class));
    }
}




and service class:




public class ChatService extends Service{

    public static Socket socket;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.e("onCreate", "onCreate");
        try {
            socket = IO.socket("http://192.168.174.1:8000");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//        Toast.makeText(AppController.getInstance(),"Created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public ChatService(Context applicationContext) {
        super();
        Log.i("HERE", "here I am!");
    }

    public ChatService() {
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            onTaskRemoved(intent);
        }

        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);


        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void run() {

                                      new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                                          @Override
                                          public void run() {

                                              if (!socket.connected()) {
                                                  socket.connect();
                                              }

                                          }
                                      });


                                  }

                              },
                0,
                5000);




        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i("EXIT", "ondestroy!");

        super.onDestroy();

    }


    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);


        Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChatService.class);
        restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

        PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmService.set(
                AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 4000,
                restartServicePendingIntent);


    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

is anyway to do this?

Comment: i correctly started service but can't restarting

Comment: You didn't even read the link, it clearly states you need foreground service with sticky notification. Requests to start background services when your app is not active will be denied.

Comment: right, i read that carefully and solved. thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vivo/honor/oppo etc , your services will get killed as soon as your app is closed.

Comment: thanks but not using that